# PHPEXCEL how to get cell value even with special characters

Tags: php, excel, utf-8, special-characters, phpexcel

When i get the cell value using the function getValue(), it returns false if the cell contains special characters, is there any solution to get the content, even if contains non UTF-8 characters? I'm looking to parse them before call the getValue() function. I will appreciate any kind of help.

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        $i=0;
        $record = array();

        foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) 
        {
            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
            $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell)
            {
                $val = $cell->getValue();
                // $val returns false or empty string ('') when the cell has special characters like ñ or another one
                $record[$i][] = $val;
            }
            $i++;
            if($i==$vueltas )
                return $record;
        }
        return $record;
    }
```

I tried with utf8_decode function and str_replace to parse the special characters but nothing happen, it still returning false. I think that is a reader problem but i can't find the code that manage it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please give an example what kind of characters and encoding is stored in your XLS-File.

Comment: PHPExcel should always return UTF-8 data; if the file is a standard spreadsheet format file, then whatever charset it uses should be converted to UTF-8 automatically. However, if it's a CSV file (or sometimes HTML as well), then the file contains no information about charset, so you must specifically tell the Reader what charset the file is using if it isn't UTF-8 using it's `setInputEncoding()` method

Comment: i'm getting the values from a .csv, and some cells have clients names with special characters, like ñ or Ñ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the problem adding:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');
$objReader->setInputEncoding('ISO-8859-1');
```

It was a problem of the header charset information.

Thanks to Mark Baker for the help!