# PHPEXCEL read special characters that didn't appear in excel sheet (â)

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I have column name in excel that have name : Hibah Ather
when I read it by PHPExcel I get name : Hibahâ ather
I tried to create new sheet and rewrite name and remove space between first and last name

I read it by :
`strtolower(trim($sheet->getCell('B' . $rowNum)->getValue()));`
[image]

Comment: What encoding are you using for the excel sheet ?

Comment: my encoding utf-8

Comment: And your database encoding ?

Comment: utf-8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998179/phpexcel-how-to-get-cell-value-even-with-special-characters ? Have you tried to dump() the value just after reading excel, before inserting in BDD ? Is the value the same ?

Comment: i read data from excel to insert it in database ... when i dump it before insert i get it with special character